# Consolidate keys in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries with an arbitrary number of repetitive keys. I want to consolidate the keys and return lists for the values (even if the key is distinct, as in 'c' and 'd' in the example below):

```
input = [{'a': 2},
         {'b': 3},
         {'c': 1},
         {'a': 3},
         {'a': 5},
         {'d': 7},
         {'b': 4}]
```

Desired output:

```
output = [{'a': [2,3,5]}, {'b': [3, 4]}, {'c': [1]}, {'d': [7]}]
```

My current method is a bit of a mess, and I'm looking for simply the code

Comment: What's your current method?

Comment: "Gimme teh codez" is not what StackOverflow is about.
Have you really given your problem sufficient thought already?
Tell us what you have tried - either the full (relevant) code or at least describe your approach in words.
You should really be asking for suggestions of an approach to take, not just code - this is not a particularly knarly problem, so you should be actually figuring out the code yourself, especially since this sounds like a homework problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 2):

A defaultdict seems like a good choice:

```
from collections import defaultdict
output = defaultdict(list)
for d in input:
    for key in d.keys():
        output[key].append(d[key])
output = [{k: output[k]} for k in output]
```

(print the intermediate values to see what is happening).

ps: you should probably not name a variable `input` since it shadows the global function by the same name..